# python - handle exceptions with curses wrapper

Tags: python, curses

I'm following the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html to setup a `curses` app in Python. According to the documentation it is recommended to use the `wrapper` as it auto initializes everything and handles exceptions.

The example provided is fairly basic by using a single function only. I'd like to use a class to wrap the curses functionality and trigger changes to the TUI. How would I use the  wrapper in that scenario? Below is an example of what I've tried so far but running the code outputs the traceback in a weird alignment and puts the terminal in a broken state which then requires a `reset`.

```
import curses
from curses import wrapper


class Test:
    def __init__(self, stdscr):
        self._stdscr = stdscr

    @classmethod
    def create(cls):
        _cls = wrapper(cls)
        return _cls

    def start(self):
        self._screen = curses.newpad(100, 100)
        self._screen.addstr(2, 2, 'test title', curses.A_STANDOUT)

        screen_rows, screen_cols = self._stdscr.getmaxyx()
        self._screen.refresh(0, 0, 0, 0, screen_rows - 1, screen_cols - 1)

        while True:
            self._stdscr.getch()
            1/0 # example of uncaught exception 


t = Test.create()
t.start()
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
                                    File "/tmp/test/test.py", line 27, in <module>
                                                                                      t.start()
                                                                                                 File "/tmp/test/test.py", line 23, in start
                                                                                                                                                1/0
          ~^~
             ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Essentially I'm looking for a solution to handle any uncaught exceptions

Answer (score -1):

You should add a try and except block to handle the zero division error
If you add the following in the right spot, your code should work better

```
while True:
    try:
        key = self._stdscr.getch()
    except ZeroDivisionError:           
        pass
```

Comment: The division by zero is just an example, I'm looking for a generic solution for an uncaught exceptions

Comment: The out put you provided earlier says ZeroDivisionError and points to the line 1/0. I believe this can help in uncaught exceptions:
    while True:
        try:
            key = self._stdscr.getch()        
        except Exception as e:  
            print(f"An uncaught exception occurred: {e}")